# Netbeans & JavaFX - Clean and build on each run?

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2, fxml

I recently started working with `JavaFX` at the Netbeans IDE. I come along with the Hello World examples as it is not that complicated, but there is one big thing that is totally annoying me:

As within my `FXML` project, I have to Clean & Build the whole project before changes get applied.

- Is this normal?
- May I skip this? 
  Working on my Lenovo Yoga, `Clean & Build & Run` takes more than a minute! That's way to long for one single changed character.

I'm using:

- Netbeans version: `7.2.1`
- Project type: `JavaFX FXML`
- JDK: `7`

Also, I can't select the `Properties -> Build -> Compile -> Compile on Save` checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netbeans 7.2.1 does not support Compile on Save for JavaFX projects, so you have to manually recompile the project each time.

One alternative is to create a normal Java project, import the JavaFX JAR (`jfxrt.jar` IIRC). Compile on Save will be available and you won't have to recompile the whole project every time you make a change (although you should still run a "clean and build" before releasing your project).

When doing that, you might lose a few JavaFx-related features - not completely sure.

Comment: Thanks for adding the required jar - I've searched for this :D

Your solution made it perfectly. I created a normal Java project and added the .jar and now, everything goes way faster^ ^

Comment: Nice workaround :) I am using JavaFX 8. So the solution is working without adding jfxrt.jar (because it's a part of JDK 8)